# Split an array in all possible combinations (not regular splitting)

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, split

Suppose I have an array,

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> array  = np.linspace(1,4,4, dtype=np.int)
>>> array
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

I want a function that will split this array in all possible parts, such that,

No split :

```
([1,2,3,4])
```

Split in `2` parts :

```
([1], [2,3,4])
([1,2], [3,4])
([1,2,3] ,[4])
```

Split in `3` parts :

```
([1], [2], [3,4])
([1,2]), [3], [4])
([1], [2,3], [4])
```

Split in `len(array)` parts :

```
([1],[2],[3],[4])
```

I know there is `np.split(array, r)`, but it will not give all possible splits. e.g. `np.split(array, 2)` will give,

```
[array([0, 1]), array([2, 3])]
```

As you can see this is not what I need. How to achieve my need?

Comment: Where's your code so far, and where specifically did you get stuck?

Comment: Sorry @smarx . I have just started to learn python. I have absolutely no idea how to do this. I know in SE we have to ask question with MWE. But right now I have no MWE.

Comment: FWIW, if you have just started to learn Python you really should get comfortable with plain Python first before you try to use complex 3rd party packages like Numpy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) to generate the indices where to split inside a loop over the number of splits:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> [np.split(array, idx) 
...  for n_splits in range(5) 
...  for idx in combinations(range(1, len(array)), n_splits)]
[[array([1, 2, 3, 4])],
 [array([1]), array([2, 3, 4])],
 [array([1, 2]), array([3, 4])],
 [array([1, 2, 3]), array([4])],
 [array([1]), array([2]), array([3, 4])],
 [array([1]), array([2, 3]), array([4])],
 [array([1, 2]), array([3]), array([4])],
 [array([1]), array([2]), array([3]), array([4])]]
```

Comment: This is precisely what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

not familiar with numpy, but you can do it in pure python using divide and conquer(whether split on this position or not ):

```
def split(a):
    if not a:
        return [[]]
    elif len(a) == 1:
        return [[a]]
    else:
        result = []
        for i in range(1, len(a) + 1):
            result += [(a[:i], *sub_split) for sub_split in split(a[i:])]
        return result

split([1,2,3])
# output => [([1], [2], [3]), ([1], [2, 3]), ([1, 2], [3]), ([1, 2, 3],)]
```

Comment: Actually I am dealing something with `numpy` , so MSeifert's answer is more convenient for me. Thanks for your effort though :)

Comment: The `else` block can be rewritten as: `return [ (a[:i], *sub_split) for i in range(1, len(a) + 1) for sub_split in split(a[i:])]`

Answer (score 2):

Looking for a clue for the task, I came here. It's my offer.

```py
from more_itertools import partitions

def partitions_as_string(string):
    return [part for part in partitions(string) if len(part) > 1]

print(partitions_as_string([1,2,3,4]))
```

Result:

```py
[[[1], [2, 3, 4]], [[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[1, 2, 3], [4]], [[1], [2], [3, 4]], [[1], [2, 3], [4]], [[1, 2], [3], [4]], [[1], [2], [3], [4]]]
```