# Find all possible solutions of Stirling number of second kind using python

Tags: python, algorithm, list, recursion

I am trying to solve a problem where i need to find all possible solutions of dividing n elements into k sets , where k can vary from 1 to n . I use Strirling number of second kind to solve this , that is
S(n,k) = S(n – 1,k – 1) + kS(n – 1,k).

So the output for S(4,2) would be something like this :

[[0, 1, 2], [3]]

[[0, 1, 3], [2]]

[[0, 2, 3], [1]]

[[0, 3], [1, 2]]

[[0, 1], [2, 3]]

[[0, 2], [1, 3]]

[[0], [1, 2, 3]]

I implemented this using recursion in python as follows :

```css
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import copy

def recursion_sterling_set(n,k):
 if k ==1:
  return [[[x for x in range(n)]]]
 elif n == k :
  return [[[x] for x in range(n)]]
 else:
  temp_n = n
  temp_k = k
  s_n_1_k_1 = recursion_sterling_set(temp_n-1,temp_k-1)
  for i in range(len(s_n_1_k_1)):
   s_n_1_k_1[i].append([temp_n-1])
  
  k_s_n_1_k= []
  temp = recursion_sterling_set(temp_n-1,temp_k)
  for i in range (k):
   temp_ = copy.deepcopy(temp)
   k_s_n_1_k += temp_
  for i in range(len(temp)*k):
   k_s_n_1_k[i][int(i/len(temp))] += [temp_n-1]
  
  return (s_n_1_k_1+k_s_n_1_k)

solution = recursion_sterling_set(int(sys.argv[1]),int(sys.argv[2]))
for i in solution:
 print (i)
print ("len= ",len(solution),"size= ",sys.getsizeof(solution))
```

This is working perfectly for small n , tried for n =10 . But for Large n (greater than 20) this is hanging probably due to memory and recursion .

I have recently started using python and wanted to understand if there was some more efficient way to implementing this . I was thinking in lines of using generators /yield to reduce the memory footprint .Would appreciate some help

This is not the same as spliting an array in all possible ways([Split an array in all possible combinations (not regular splitting)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45780190/split-an-array-in-all-possible-combinations-not-regular-splitting)) . It is a bit different, for example number of ways of arranging 3 elements in sets of 2 , would generate 3 solution as follows :

[[1,2],[3]] , [[1,3],[2]] , [[2,3],[1]]

while spliting an array solution would generate only the following 2 :

[[1,2],[3]], [[1],[2,3]]

Comment: this is better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). You are better of trying your luck there.

Comment: The cited *duplicate* question is about partitioning, not the type of combinations being discussed here.

Comment: Following @cdlane, this question ***does allow*** for breaking/rearranging the sequence of items, while the so-called _duplicate_ question ***does not***.

Answer (score 0):

I came up a iteration version after reading the unpublished book **Combinatorial Generation** by Frank Ruskey.

```
def stirling3_iterative(a, n, k, f):
    stack = [(n, k, a)]
    while stack:
        n, k, a = stack.pop()
        if n == k:
            f(a)
        else:
            for i in range(0, k):
                a[n] = i
                stack.append((n - 1, k, a[:]))
                a[n] = n - 1
            if k > 1:
                a[n] = k - 1
                stack.append((n - 1, k - 1, a[:]))
                a[n] = n - 1
```

we can call it by :

```
def helper(n=11, k=5):
    b = [i - 1 for i in range(n + 1)]
    r1 = 0

    def g(a):
        nonlocal r1
        r = defaultdict(list)
        for i in range(1, n + 1):
            r[a[i]].append(i)
        print(r)
        r1 += 1

    start = time.time()
    stirling3_iterative(b, n, k, g)
    print("len= ", r1, time.time() - start)
```

In case you want to know why this iterative come from. The original the recursive version from the book is:

```
def stirling3(a, n, k, f):
    if n == k:
        f(a)
    else:
        for i in range(0, k):
            a[n] = i
            stirling3(a, n - 1, k, f)  # this call String
            a[n] = n - 1
        if k > 1:
            a[n] = k - 1
            stirling3(a, n - 1, k - 1, f)
            a[n] = n - 1
```

They print the different order of result. But any way the count and the result is right.